# numerically solve non-linear system of equations on limited definition interval using python

Tags: python, solver, gekko, nonlinear-functions

Assume the following problem:
I have to functions, one of which is parameterized by t, and both are defined on the independent variable z: f(t, z, *ags), g(z, *args).

I want to find a pair of values (t0, z0) so that

the functions and their derivatives with respect to z are the same
f(t0, z0, *args) = g(z0, *args)
and
df/dz(t0, z0, *args) = dg/dz(z0, *args).

I know a solution exists and I got a reasonable starting point (tS, zS).
However, at least one of the functions is defined only on a specified interval [zL .. zH] (which I know).

My question now is, which is the best way to solve the system of equations numerically in python.

I tried scipys fsolve, but it seems to fail, I think because it can't handle the limited definition interval. I tried the differential_evolution package, for just minimizing a composite function, but that seems like complete overkill.

I have expressions for all functions and their derivatives (although they are complicated).

There certainly must be a simple python rootfinder, which is able to solve a system of two non-linear equations, which are defined only on a limited interval?!

For some reason all I find is either able to solve a system of equations, not taking into account limits, or is able to take limits but only solve a single equation at a time...

Would be really grateful, if someone could point me in the right direction where to look!

Answer (score 3):

This question requires the assumptions that 1) multiple solutions exist and 2) at least one solution is in the bounds of the specified interval. If these assumptions are not met, your problem becomes optimization -- minimizing the difference between your functions.

I generated the following example that meets the assumptions:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def f(t,z):
    return t**2 + z + z**2 + np.sin(z)
def g(z):
    return z**2
def dfdz(t,z):
    return 1 + 2*z + np.cos(z)
def dgdz(z):
    return 2*z

def solve(x):
    t,z = x

    #residual array
    r = np.zeros(2)
    #match equations
    r[0] = (f(t,z) - g(z))**2
    #match derivatives
    r[1] = dfdz(t,z) - dgdz(z)

    return r

x0 = [10,-10]
x = fsolve(solve,x0)
t,z = x
print(t,z)
```

At these initial conditions, the answer is [3.06998012761 -9.42477800292]. 
Requiring bounded variables is possible with fsolve by adding a residual when outside the range. This is a pretty hacky solution that is not very robust.
We can bound z to the range of [-5,0] (where there is another correct answer) with these modifications:

```
def solve(x,zL,zH):
    t,z = x

    #penalize deviation from range
    if z < zL:
        e = z - zL
    elif z > zH:
        e = z - zH
    else:
        e = 0

    #residual array
    r = np.zeros(2)
    #match equations
    r[0] = (f(t,z) - g(z))**2 + (e)**2
    #match derivatives
    r[1] = dfdz(t,z) - dgdz(z)

    return r


x0 = [10,-10]
x = fsolve(solve,x0,args=(-5,0))
t,z = x
print(t,z)
```

The new answer is [ 1.77245385 -3.14159263].

As previously mentioned, bounded variables are more commonly addressed in optimization problems, so an optimization package would handle it more intuitively. In python, there is the standard scipy.optimize.minimize, or much more powerful packages such as [Pyomo](http://www.pyomo.org/) or [GEKKO](http://gekko.readthedocs.io). Here is the equivalent problem in GEKKO:

```
from gekko import GEKKO

#initialize a GEKKO model
m = GEKKO()

#add GEKKO variables
t = m.Var(value = -10)
z = m.Var(value = -10, lb=-5, ub=0)

#define the constraints
m.Equation(t**2 + z + z**2 + m.sin(z) == z**2)
m.Equation(1 + 2*z + m.cos(z) == 2*z)

#solve a system of non-dynamic equations
m.options.IMODE = 1 
m.solve(disp=False)

print(t.value,z.value)
```

[-1.772454] [-3.142608]